# sas macro : how to make multiful column using macro?

Tags: sas

I'm SAS user.

I want to assign year columns using date values.

for example, here is my code, below.

I want to make Y_2010, Y_2011, Y_2012 , Y_2013, Y_2014 in work.total data set.
but there is only Y_2014 as a result.

How can I change the code as I can get right result which I intended first?

```
options mcompilenote = all;

%let a = Y_ ;


%macro B(YMIN, YMAX) ;
%do i = &YMIN %to &YMAX ;

DATA TOTAL ;
SET SASUSER.EMPDATA    ;
IF YEAR(HIREDATE) = &i  THEN  &a&i = 1 ;                                              
ELSE &a&i = 0 ;
RUN;

%end;
%mend;

%B (2010, 2014) ;
```

Comment: There are faster and better ways to create dummy variables or dummy code variables. This is most likely a transpose or dummy coding problem in reality.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are repeatedly re-creating the output dataset only the final version is available. To fix the macro move the %DO loop inside the DATA step so that you are generating all of the variables in a single data step.

```
%macro B(YMIN, YMAX) ;
DATA TOTAL ;
  SET SASUSER.EMPDATA    ;
%do i = &YMIN %to &YMAX ;
  IF YEAR(HIREDATE) = &i  THEN  &a&i = 1 ;                                              
  ELSE &a&i = 0 ;
%end;
RUN;
%mend;
```

But there is no need to a macro for this.  Just use normal SAS statements.  For example you could use an ARRAY statement to define the variables and then loop over the array and set the values.  Note that the result of a boolean expression in SAS is 0 when false and 1 when true so you can eliminate the IF/THEN/ELSE statement and just use an assignment statement.

```
DATA TOTAL ;
  SET SASUSER.EMPDATA    ;
  array &a &a&ymin - &a&ymax;
  do i=&ymin to &ymax ;
    &a[i-&ymin+1] = (year(hiredata)=i);
  end;
  drop i;
RUN;
```